# Importing variables which are generated in an endless loop into another python file

Tags: python, file, variables, import, while-loop

I´m very new to python and I think that´s a basic question, however, I struggle.

I have one file, upload.py, which searchs for the newest .csv file in a path. That .csv file is updated every x seconds with new values. An endless while loop in upload.py reads that continously updated csv file and stores the new values as a variable. (If you have better suggestions, Iam always up for that).

```
#upload.py
CO2_Files= r"C:\Users\BVT\Desktop\Software_BACVisSingle\data"
p = Path(CO2_Files)

files = []
for entry in os.scandir(p):
    if entry.is_file():
        files.append(entry)
#print("files - {}".format(files))

latest_file = max(files, key= os.path.getctime)
#print("The latest file is: ", latest_file)

while True:
    sleep(10-time() %10 )
    with open (latest_file) as f:
        newest_measurement= pd.read_csv(latest_file, sep=";", encoding= "unicode_escape", header = 0, skiprows=[0], usecols=[0,2,4], names =["ts","CO2", "p"])
        newest_value=newest_measurement.tail(1)
        #print(type(newest_value))
        #print(newest_value)
        df= pd.DataFrame(newest_value)
        Timepoint=df.iloc[0,0]
        CO2_concentration=df.iloc[0,1]
        print(Timepoint) 
        print(CO2_concentration)
```

To further work with these constant changing variables (Timepoint, CO2_concentration), I need to import them into a second python file, called server+CO2.py. How can I import those variables?

If I import the whole upload.py file into server+CO2.py, the server+CO2.py file will stuck in the endless loop of upload.py and will not execute the other parts of the file.

If I only import the two variables, it doesn´t seem to make a difference.
I thought about the **main**==**name** function, but I don´t think thats the solution here.

Any advice would be great! Thanks!

Comment: So every time these two variables are created, you want to use them somewhere else separately without stopping the infinite loop. Is that your problem?

Comment: Yes, I want to import these variables ever x seconds without breaking the loop.

Comment: Then, Instead of importing them into another Python file, merge both files, and every time these variables are changed, call your desired function with a new thread.

Comment: But since this is an endless loop, how can I execute the other parts of the file which are below the loop? Kinda stupid question, but I have no idea.